# foreach array_unique not working

Tags: laravel, foreach, distinct, laravel-blade, array-unique

I have this code:

```
@foreach($files['folders'] as $file)
  @foreach(array_unique($file['file_name']) as $names)
    <tr><td>{{$names}}</td></tr>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Returns null.
I want array `$file` display only DISTINCT `$file['file_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to solve this problem in your controller, try this:

```
//TheController.php
... whatever code you have in controller...
$seen = [];
$unique_files = [];
foreach($files['folders'] as $file)
    if(!isset($seen[$file['file_name']]) {
       $seen[$file['file_name'] = true;
       $unique_files[] = $file;
    }
}
$files['folders'] = $unique_files;

//Then pass $files as usual to your view
```

In your template file now you have only unique values:

```
@foreach($files['folders'] as $file)
   <tr><td>{{$file['file_name']}}</td></tr>
@endforeach
```

I hope this works for you